# Пересечение разных по объему множеств

Tags: sql, oracle

Есть 2 набора записей с одинаковыми полями. Но с разным количеством строк. При этом большее количество строк может быть как в первом множестве, так и во втором.

Необходимо вывести все строки и в отдельном столбце проставить признак - 1, если такая запись есть в первом множестве, 0 - если в первом множестве ее нет (то есть она есть только во втором). Идентичность записей - по совпадению значений всех полей. При этом записи по совокупности значений полей уникальны внутри одного множества.

То есть как сделать вот так примерно:

```
with aw (v1, v2, v3) as
(
  select 1, 2, 4 from dual
  union all
  select 1, 3, 4 from dual
  union all
  select 1, 3, 2 from dual
  union all
  select 5, 2, 4 from dual
  union all
  select 1, 7, 4 from dual
  union all
  select 1, 2, 6 from dual
),
bw (v1, v2, v3) as
(
  select 1, 2, 4 from dual
  union all
  select 1, 3, 40 from dual
  union all
  select 1, 30, 2 from dual
  union all
  select 5, 2, 4 from dual
  union all
  select 10, 7, 4 from dual
  union all
  select 1, 2, 6 from dual  
)
select 
  aw.v1, aw.v2, aw.v3,
  bw.v1, bw.v2, bw.v3,
  case when aw.v1 = bw.v1 and aw.v2 = bw.v2 and aw.v3 = bw.v3 then 1 else 0 end
from
aw
cross join
bw
```

Comment: А как вы сами пробовали? Сходу на ум приходит оператор case

Comment: Да, case, но чтобы анализировать case нужно сформировать общую выборку по условию идентичности значений в полях - а как ее сделать - не понимаю.

Comment: FULL OUTER JOIN, если надо сразу посмотреть в обе стороны. Или LEFT JOIN, если только в одну.

Comment: PS. Меньший объём набора - не гарантия того, что в нём нет записей, отсутствующих в наборе большего объёма...

Comment: *вот так примерно* CROSS JOIN не подойдёт. См. выше.

Comment: @Akina - добавил в вопрос пример запроса, как можно разрулить его по выборкам? Поздно прочитал ваш второй ответ ((

Comment: Замените тип связывания. Начните с тупого SELECT *. Сразу увидите, что, как и куда.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with aw (v1, v2, v3) as
(
  select 1, 2, 4 from dual
  union all
  select 1, 3, 4 from dual
  union all
  select 1, 3, 2 from dual
  union all
  select 5, 2, 4 from dual
  union all
  select 1, 7, 4 from dual
  union all
  select 1, 2, 6 from dual
),
bw (v1, v2, v3) as
(
  select 1, 2, 4 from dual
  union all
  select 1, 3, 40 from dual
  union all
  select 1, 30, 2 from dual
  union all
  select 5, 2, 4 from dual
  union all
  select 10, 7, 4 from dual
  union all
  select 1, 2, 6 from dual  
)
SELECT COALESCE(aw.v1, bw.v1) v1,
       COALESCE(aw.v2, bw.v2) v2,
       COALESCE(aw.v3, bw.v3) v3,
       CASE WHEN aw.v1 IS NULL THEN 'in bw'
            WHEN bw.v1 IS NULL THEN 'in aw'
            ELSE                    'in both' END in_where
FROM aw
FULL OUTER JOIN bw ON aw.v1=bw.v1 AND aw.v2=bw.v2 AND aw.v3=bw.v3
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое, думаю то, что нужно